# Tor is not hiding my location

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, location

I am trying to watch live FIFA matches on this [site](https://www.fubo.tv/welcome) which is not available in my country so I am using Tor. However Tor is not hiding my location.

Screenshot explains it better

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In tor browser, try going to https://www.ip-tracker.org/. This will verify weather tor is hiding your location or not. If the site does show your real location in tor browser than yes your tor is not working correctly. However if it shows an unknown location the tor is working correctly.

The issue you are describing does not sound tor related; what's most likely happening is this website is ONLY accepting ip addresses from their approved country list, or they are resolving the ip address and dter

Answer (score 0):

> active content, such as Java, Javascript, Adobe Flash, Adobe Shockwave, QuickTime, RealAudio, ActiveX controls, and VBScript <...> can access anything that your user account can access. Some of these technologies, such as Java and Adobe Flash for instance, <...> may have the ability to ignore your configured proxy settings, and therefore bypass Tor and share information directly to other sites <...> may be able to store data, such as cookies, completely separate from your browser or operating system data stores. Therefore, these technologies must be disabled in your browser to use Tor safely. <...> Alternatively, you may find a Live CD or USB operating system more to your liking.

Source: [So I'm totally anonymous if I use Tor?](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AmITotallyAnonymous) (See it for more details.)